# How to redirect page after auto login with Curl keeping session?

Tags: php, html, curl, autologin

I'm having a problem: after auto login using Curl PHP the site does not load css files and images.
My solution would then be to write the login session and redirect the page.

Code:

```
<?php
$cookie="cookie.txt";
$login_url = "https://online.hinode.com.br/loja_valida.asp";
$target_url="https://online.hinode.com.br/detalhes.asp?IdProduto=1294&ssp=1044632862SSP20171218HP180256";
$useragent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1";

$field['loja_consultor'] = '228621';
$field['estado'] = 'SP';
$field['acessar'] = 'Acessar';

$datafield = http_build_query($field);

$ch = curl_init($login_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $login_url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $datafield);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_exec($ch);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $target_url);

$ket_qua = curl_exec($ch);



$ph = header ("location:42018010322060614551.htm", curl_exec($ch));

echo $ph;


curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are saying you want to keep the session generated by the endpoint url, I don't think you can do that since `cURL` is stateless.

Comment: @Rasclatt What do you suggest me?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `base` tag could solve most of your concerns:CSS and images.

Try the following code:

```
<?php
$cookie="cookie.txt";
$login_url = "https://online.hinode.com.br/loja_valida.asp";
$target_url="https://online.hinode.com.br/detalhes.asp?IdProduto=1294&ssp=1044632862SSP20171218HP180256";
$useragent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1";

$field['loja_consultor'] = '228621';
$field['estado'] = 'SP';
$field['acessar'] = 'Acessar';

$datafield = http_build_query($field);

$ch = curl_init($login_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $login_url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $datafield);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_exec($ch);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $target_url);
$ket_qua = curl_exec($ch);

//add base URL
$baseUrlStr = '<head><base href="https://online.hinode.com.br/">';
$ket_qua=str_replace('<head>',$baseUrlStr,$ket_qua);

echo $ket_qua;
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: First of all, thank you.

The css and images loaded as I would like, but the problem is that now when I click on any section, link, image or menu returns to the login screen.

Comment: Yes. The suggestion could only solve the CSS and image loading issue, not the session issue. But why do you need "click"? If you use CURL, you should use script to get other section/link.

Comment: In this case, in specific, it is necessary that the user be able to access the other sections of the page, when clicking on any menu item needs to be redirected.Thus, the session needs to be maintained. Any suggestion?
I tried using `wget` to download the files and bring up the cover page while retaining the session, but it did not work.

Comment: Because you use CURL, your webserver is working as a proxy. You may parse all the links and update the links to execute your command (e.g. another curl page). It's very complicated,  and there are some discussions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120683/curl-browser-emulator-with-php